# X must be atomic for sort list - confusionMatrix [caret package]

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have a problem that I would like a help, if possible. I searched all related posts here on the stack overflow but I did not find any answer that could help me. Others with different codes and purposes had this problem, but the answers here did not help me. Therefore, I created a new topic. It's a probably an easy thing, since I am new to R, so I apologize and thank you in advance.

I am investigating the distribution records of cetaceans reported by citizen scientists and cetacean experts in Brazil. I divided my area in 5x5km grids and for each grid I have if a cetacean was sighted and who did the sighting (citizen scientist or cetacean experts). Now, I would like to do a confusion matrix to compare Citizen science (CS) x Cetacean expert (CE) data.
Here'my code and data:

CE data - each grid I have the information if Cetacean Experts sighted a cetacean (CE) or if there were no sighting 'NO'
FID     CE
1       'NO'
2       'NO'
3       'NO'
4       'CE'
5       'CE'
6       'CE'
7       'NO'
8       'CE'
9       'NO'
10      'CE'

CS data - each grid I have the information if Citizen scientists sighted a cetacean (CS) or if there were no sighting 'NO'
FID     CE
1       'NO'
2       'NO'
3       'NO'
4       'NO'
5       'NO'
6       'NO'
7       'CS'
8       'CS'
9       'CS'
10      'CS'

Now my code:
library(caret)

```html
library(caret)

#Predicted - Citizen science sightings in each grid
brydecs=read.table("pred_bryCS1.txt",header=T)
View(brydecs)
#Reference - Cetacean expert sightings in each grid
brydece=read.table("obs_bryCE1.txt",header=T)
View(brydece)
x=table(survey1,survey) #Here I got the error: 'x' must be atomic for sort list
#End of code
```

What is the problem here? I can't continue to do the confusionMatrix. If I continue > confusionMatrix(brydecs,brydece), skipping the table code, I get the same error.

If somebody can help me I would trully appreciate.

Thanks,
Rodrigo

Comment: Can you run `str(survey1)` and `str(survey)` and show the results? for a confusion matrix in `caret`, these much be factors with the same levels

Comment: Actually, survey and survey1 do not exist. Sorry. That was a different attempt I was doing. The correct is (brydecs,brydece). When I do str for brydece and brydecs:

Comment: > str(brydecs)
'data.frame': 22 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ CS.: Factor w/ 2 levels "CS'","NO'": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
> str(brydece)
'data.frame': 22 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ CE: Factor w/ 2 levels "CE'","NO'": 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...

Comment: @topepo I just put what you ask. Do you think you know what my problem is now? Thanks in advance